# Selecting a list of nodes through multiple path addresses in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Consider following Cyphers:

```
MATCH (n{name: "John"})-[:Colleague]-(m) RETURN m;
```

This query finds `Colleague(s)` of `John(s)`. Now another one:

```
MATCH (n{name: "John"})-[:Friend]-()-[:Colleague]-(m) RETURN m;
```

This one finds `Colleague(s)` of `John(s)'` `Friend(s)`. And now the last one:

```
MATCH (n{name: "John"})-[:Colleague]-()-[:Friend]-(m) RETURN m;
```

Finally, this one finds `Friend(s)` of `John(s)'` `Colleague(s)`. What I'm looking for is a Cypher query which finds the union of all of the nodes found by the given queries.

Please note that this is just an example. What I'm actually asking here is how to find one set of nodes using multiple paths? Something like:

```
MATCH (n{name: "John"})
    -[:Colleague]- /
    -[:Friend]-()-[:Colleague]- /
    -[:Colleague]-()-[:Friend]-
    (m) RETURN m;
```

Comment: In query language, a UNION is combining the results of multiple queries (additive), and JOIN is taking the intersection of multiple queries (reductive). If I understand you right, you want the JOIN, right?

Comment: @Tezra I'm looking for UNION; all the nodes accessible starting from the `n` node(s), taking any of the given paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse variables across multiple matches to reference the same node (JOIN pattern). Example

```
MATCH (n{name: "John"})-[:Colleague]-(m)
MATCH (n)-[:Friend]-()-[:Colleague]-(m)
MATCH (n)-[:Colleague]-()-[:Friend]-(m)
RETURN m;
```

Here, "John" is matched once, and used as the start of each match, and m is the join of the interesting node of each match. If there is more than one instance of "John", this query will process all of them separately. If all "Johns" should be treated as the same person, than just don't reuse n.

If you want the UNION instead of the JOIN, you can just collect them like this

```
MATCH (n{name: "John"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:Colleague]-(c)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:Friend]-(fc)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:Friend]-()-[:Colleague]-(fc)
WITH c+collect(fc)+collect(cf) AS nodez
UNWIND nodez AS m
RETURN DISTINCT m;
```

Comment: I would really like your first solution if worked! But so far when test it, the `(m)`s are not joined. Are you sure if you reuse node variables, they could be joined together?

Comment: Yes. You can test this with a simpler pattern. `CREATE (a:TEST{id:1})-[:HAS]->(b:TEST{id:2})-[:HAS]->(c:TEST{id:3}) CREATE (d:TEST{id:4})-[:HAS]->(b) CREATE (d)-[:HAS]->(z:TEST{id:5}) RETURN *`
 And then 
`MATCH (a:TEST{id:1})-[:HAS]->(b) MATCH (d:TEST{id:4})-[:HAS]->(b) RETURN *`
(http://console.neo4j.org/r/a5qwio)

Comment: @Mehran The first version is if you want only nodes that satisfy all 3 (AKA JOIN). You have to use UNION or COLLECT() if you want all nodes that satisfy any pattern.

Comment: I simplified the UNION version to be like the JOIN version.

Answer (score 6):

In this particular case, you can use a variable-length relationship with multiple relationship types. However, to prevent bad paths (colleague of colleague, friend of friend, and just friends) we have to do some additional filtering to ensure that there is at least one colleague relationship in the path.

```
MATCH (n{name: "John"})-[r:Colleague|Friend*1..2]-(m) 
WHERE 'Colleague' in [rel in r | type(rel)]
RETURN m;
```

Also, I highly recommend that you use a label on your nodes, and use an index on the label / name combination so your lookup to your John node is fast, instead of having to check every single node in your graph.

This query won't be as performant as queries doing a UNION, but with an index lookup and only two traversals, with not too many relationships, it should work fine.

Comment: While your solution is absolutely valid and working (I might even use it for the problem I have at hand). But is there a way to implement arbitrary paths? Like UNION but at the same time, it can be part of a bigger query. It seems to me that UNION can only be the outer-most level of a query and nothing can wrap it.

Comment: I added a separate answer for this one.

Answer (score 2):

What about simply use an [UNION](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/union/)? Try it:

```
MATCH (n{name: "John"})-[:Colleague]-(m)
RETURN m as node

UNION

MATCH (n{name: "John"})-[:Friend]-()-[:Colleague]-(m)
RETURN m as node

UNION

MATCH (n{name: "John"})-[:Colleague]-()-[:Friend]-(m)
RETURN m as node
```

Comment: That's great but what if I don't want to finish my query here? I mean I'm trying to embed this in some bigger query but it seems UNION can not be an inner part of a bigger query. Is that right? It would be great if you can show me how to find nodes having a relation of type :Sibling with the found `(m)`s. And I don't mean adding `-[:Sibling]->(o)` to each of the sub-queries. I'm looking for a way to include this late part once, linked to the result of aggregated `(m)`s.

Comment: I believe that is is not possible with UNION. To achieve this goal use the @Tezra approach showed in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44139032/6835358) (adapted): `MATCH (n{name: "John"})-[:Colleague]-(m)
WITH n, collect(m) as z
MATCH (n)-[:Friend]-()-[:Colleague]-(m)
WITH n, z+collect(m) as z
MATCH (n)-[:Colleague]-()-[:Friend]-(m)
WITH z+collect(m) AS m
UNWIND m AS node
MATCH (node)-[:Sibling]->(s)
RETURN node, s` This will give to you the same result as UNION and you will could continue the query.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a separate answer for dealing with UNION queries while retaining the ability to process the unioned results.

We actually have a knowledge base article on [post-UNION processing](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/post-union-processing/) with a few different approaches.

With APOC procedures you can perform the UNION within `apoc.cypher.run()`, and take the returned unioned results and keep operating on them.

Comment: For those without APOC, You can use collect() like a union (https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-union-query-using-collect-clause/)

Answer (score 1):

This simple query should work:

```
MATCH p=({name: "John"})-[:Friend*0..1]-()-[:Colleague]-()-[:Friend*0..1]-(m) 
WHERE LENGTH(p) <= 2
RETURN m;
```

It uses the variable length pattern `*0..1` to make the `Friend` relationships optional. The `WHERE` clause filters out paths that are more than 2 relationships long.